# deploying gatsby multilingual site behind cloudfront and s3

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront, multilingual

I developed a multilingual site in gatsby with gatsby-plugin-react-i18next for the i18n.

I deployed it to s3 and put a cloudfront distribution in front of it.

We configured s3 as static web site hosting and make all the files public.

We can reach http://our-site.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/en/ and everything works fine (we can switch between languages)

The problem is on cloudfront side, I mean If try to get https://my-distribution.cloudfront.net/en/ I have access denied

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>P79H5EABEWW5KH1T</RequestId>
<HostId>OJ1GdIe3iLlj+fEJO4EwTNlhAAXjRV7M3bwKUDr4UXjXKWor8Rr+K9m9cR7mALxNuuDDPN3uHsA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Of course the origin of the distribution is the s3.
I'm missing something...

Comment: The solution I found is to use Lambda@Edge in order to serve the right locale.
https://dev.to/danielbayerlein/how-to-handle-a-multilingual-static-site-with-amazon-cloudfront-hosted-on-amazon-s3-3mc4

Comment: CloudFront Functions was launched after that article was written. If you'd prefer, you can also accomplish the same with CloudFront Functions all within the CloudFront console. Here's the example implementation: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/url-rewrite-single-page-apps